# Angular bootstrap custom input material layout not working

Tags: angular, typescript, bootstrap-4, autofill

I have created an input styled same as material input design in my angular project. It's working fine except in IE-11. To solve the IE-11 issue I created an Angular Directive and changed behavior with a class adding into parent element. It's working fine in all browsers, but sometimes it isn't working perfectly. Inside the directive I check if the value is not empty or not null, then add a class 'input-focused' in the parent div. When the input is autofilled by the browser, the labels are not moved to the top like material. If I click on the page, then it moves.

Can anyone help me to solve this issue, here my code snippet and output:

[image: Screenshot of 2 login cards]

## HTML input

```
<div class="group">
    <input type="text" required="required" autocomplete="off" formControlName="email" appAutoFocusElement />
    <label **ngIf="email.error">Error message</label>
</div>
```

## Directive

```
import { AfterContentInit, Directive, ElementRef, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appAutoFocusElement]'
})
export class AutoFocusDirective implements AfterContentInit {
  @Input() public appAutoFocusElement: boolean;
  public constructor(private el: ElementRef) { }

  // find the prent element until find parent
  public getParentsElement = (elem, selector) => {
    for (; elem && elem !== document; elem = elem.parentNode) {
      if (elem.matches(selector)) { return elem; }
    }
    return null;
  }

  public ngAfterContentInit() {
    // check the if metch
    const parentElementfindResult = this.getParentsElement(this.el.nativeElement, '.group');

    setTimeout(() => {
      // on load set focus in parent
      if (this.el.nativeElement.value !== '' || this.el.nativeElement.value !== null) {
        if (parentElementfindResult === null || parentElementfindResult === undefined) { return; }
        parentElementfindResult.classList.add('input-focused');
      }

      // add in specific input focus depend on class 'first-focus'
      if (this.el.nativeElement.classList.contains('first-focus')) {
        this.el.nativeElement.focus();
      }

      this.el.nativeElement.addEventListener('focusin', () => {
        if (parentElementfindResult === null || parentElementfindResult === undefined) { return; }
        parentElementfindResult.classList.add('input-focused');
      });

      // when unfocus
      this.el.nativeElement.addEventListener('blur', () => {
        if (parentElementfindResult === null || parentElementfindResult === undefined) { return; }
        if (this.el.nativeElement.value !== '') {
          parentElementfindResult.classList.add('input-focused');
        } else {
          parentElementfindResult.classList.remove('input-focused');
        }
      });
    }, 500); 
  }
}
```

Comment: It's a CSS issue. Webkit-transform doesn't work in IE11. Hope this [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/-webkit-transform-3d) could help

Comment: Not used to CSS transform it's an positioning element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have made solutions about this one updating Directive for Input

using a function

```
checkAutofill(input) {
    if (!input.value) {
      const style = window.getComputedStyle(input);
      if (style.content !== this.autofillContent) {
        return false;
      }
    }
    const parentElementfindResult = this.getParentsElement(this.el.nativeElement, '.group');
    parentElementfindResult.classList.add('input-focused');
    return true;
  }
```

Call function a couple of times like:

```
let interval = 0;
const intervalId = setInterval(() => {
  if (this.checkAutofill(this.el.nativeElement) || interval++ >= 20) {
    clearInterval(intervalId);
  }
}, 100);
```

And full Directive code here

```
import { AfterContentInit, Directive, ElementRef, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appAutoFocusElement]'
})
export class AutoFocusDirective implements AfterContentInit {
  autofillContent = `"${String.fromCharCode(0xFEFF)}"`;
  @Input() public appAutoFocusElement: boolean;
  public constructor(private el: ElementRef) { }

  // find the prent element until find parent
  public getParentsElement = (elem, selector) => {
    for (; elem && elem !== document; elem = elem.parentNode) {
      if (elem.matches(selector)) { return elem; }
    }
    return null;
  }

  public ngAfterContentInit() {

    let interval = 0;
    const intervalId = setInterval(() => {
      if (this.checkAutofill(this.el.nativeElement) || interval++ >= 20) {
        clearInterval(intervalId);
      }
    }, 100);

    // check the if metch
    const parentElementfindResult = this.getParentsElement(this.el.nativeElement, '.group');

    setTimeout(() => {
      // on load set focus in parent
      if (this.el.nativeElement.value !== '') {
        if (parentElementfindResult === null || parentElementfindResult === undefined) { return; }
        parentElementfindResult.classList.add('input-focused');
      }

      if (this.el.nativeElement.classList.contains('first-focus')) {
        this.el.nativeElement.focus();
      }

      this.el.nativeElement.addEventListener('focusin', () => {
        if (parentElementfindResult === null || parentElementfindResult === undefined) { return; }
        parentElementfindResult.classList.add('input-focused');
      });

      this.el.nativeElement.addEventListener('change', () => {
        if (parentElementfindResult === null || parentElementfindResult === undefined) { return; }
        parentElementfindResult.classList.add('input-focused');
      });

      // when unfocus
      this.el.nativeElement.addEventListener('blur', () => {
        if (parentElementfindResult === null || parentElementfindResult === undefined) { return; }
        if (this.el.nativeElement.value !== '') {
          parentElementfindResult.classList.add('input-focused');
        } else {
          parentElementfindResult.classList.remove('input-focused');
        }
      });
    }, 500);
  }

  checkAutofill(input) {
    if (!input.value) {
      const style = window.getComputedStyle(input);
      if (style.content !== this.autofillContent) {
        return false;
      }
    }
    const parentElementfindResult = this.getParentsElement(this.el.nativeElement, '.group');
    parentElementfindResult.classList.add('input-focused');
    return true;
  }
}
```